# Порядок потока в исходном файле

Tags: css

Привет, как можно придумать чтобы порядок элементов в потоке шёл h2 h3 h1, а визуально всё выглядело так https://jsfiddle.net/wobsrph1/

```css
h1{
  width:200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height:400px;
  float:left;
}
h2{
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  float:right;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height:100px;
}
h3{
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  float:right;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<h1>3</h1>
<h2>1</h2>
<h3>2</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
h2 {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  float: right;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 100px;
}
h3 {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  float: right;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
<h1>h1</h1>
```